# PHP mysql_query automatically stripping slashes?

Tags: php, mysql

I am echoing the statement out right above the mysql_query statement, and for some reason the slashes in the csv file are being stripped? I get the error you can see below. Any insights?

```
echo "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" . $csv . "' INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES";
mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" . $csv . "' INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES") or die(mysql_error());
```

ERROR:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\FileClean\output\6eai1mikqkidpe1re77e8a6jn2trial_new.csv' INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' IGNORE 1 LINES

Can't find file 'C:FileCleanoutput6eai1mikqkidpe1re77e8a6jn2trial_new.csv'
```

Comment: can u give us what `$csv` equals or an example of it?

Comment: did you escape the slashes? i.e. "\\"

Comment: yo can see what $csv equals in the statement I echoed out above (right below "ERROR")

Comment: C:\FileClean\output\6eai1mikqkidpe1re77e8a6jn2trial_new.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the slashes by adding another slash in front of each in the $csv file path.

example:

```
C:\\FileClean\\output\\6eai1mikqkidpe1re77e8a6jn2trial_new.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

`\` is a special character--the string escape character--so it's probably doing strange things. Try `addslashes` to make them `\\` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the slashes in $csv, like so:

```
"C:\\FileClean\\output\\6eai1mikqkidpe1re77e8a6jn2trial_new.csv"
```